# Injection preserves sub $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I'm reading a proposition from this [note](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/APA_lecture_notes_1819.pdf), i.e.,

---

**Proposition 1.17.** If $X$ is a random variable on a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Borelmeasurable, then $Y=g(X)$ is a $\sigma(X)$-measurable random variable, which is equivalent to saying that $\sigma(Y) \subset \sigma(X)$ : the information carried by $Y$ is in general less than that carried by $X$.

Note that it can be strictly less: if you think e.g. about the case $Y=X^2$, then the information about the sign of $X$ is lost in $Y$; on the other hand, if the function $g$ is **invertible** (meaning that one can write $\left.X=g^{-1}(Y)\right)$, then $\sigma(Y)=\sigma(X)$

---

It seems to me being invertible here means being injective. Could you confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: Injective is not enough. If $g$ is bijective and its inverse is also Borel  measuarble then you are fine.

Comment: @geetha290krm Could you confirm if my understanding is correct? We need to prove that $\{X \in B\} \in \sigma(Y)$ for all $B \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. If $g$ is injective, then $\{X \in B\} = \{Y \in g(B)\}$. If $g$ is bijective and its inverse $g^{-1}$ is measurable, then $g(B)$ is the [inverse image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image) of $B$ under $g^{-1}$ and thus $g(B) \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.